# Sharepoint display list item attachment using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Below is the script used to display a attachment of a list item using web service.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/js/SPAPI_Core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/js/SPAPI_Lists.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAttachments(List,ID){
var lists = new SPAPI_Lists('Your File name');
var items = lists.getAttachmentCollection(List,ID);

if (items.status == 200){

var rows = items.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('Attachment');
var str="";
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
temp=rows[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
fileName=temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

str+='<a href="'+temp+'" target="_blank">'+fileName+'</a>'+"<br />";
}
document.getElementById("att"+ID).innerHTML = str;
}else{
alert('There was an error: ' + items.statusText);
}
}
</script>
```

---

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(@Attachments) != '0'">
  <div id="att{@ID}" style="padding: 10px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    getAttachments("Posts",<xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>);
  </script> </xsl:if>
```

---

```
reference URL: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31895/Displaying-Attachments-with-the-Data-View-Web-Part
```

The above script is used to display attachments... but no use...

please help me if im missing something

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I followed instructions from your reference link and it worked.
This is what I did.

1. Downloaded SPAPI_Core and SPAPI_list hs files under siteassets/js folder.
2. dropped your script above in a content editor web part in the page.
3. Added your XSL Code above to my xsl file.

It worked. Just make sure to change your site path and list name.